# I want to add a single line comment in each JAXB generated file that have been generated using the org.codehaus.mojo jaxb2-maven-plugin plugin

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm generating JAXB classes from an XSD using XJC
    org.codehaus.mojo
    jaxb2-maven-plugin
    2.2

I want to add a single line comment at the top of each generated file, what is the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: I've managed to use the plugin : com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin to transform a comment at the top of the file to what I wanted in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin
                replacer
                1.5.2
                
                    
                        prepare-package
                        
                            replace

```
                <basedir>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com/deltarail/nexus/cis/map/jaxb/generated</basedir>

                <includes>                       
                    <include>*.java</include>                            
                </includes>      

                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.11</token>
                        <value>// CSOFF: a.*</value>                          
                    </replacement>


                <replacement>
                        <token>public class</token>
                        <value>@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
public class</value>                          
                    </replacement>


                </replacements>
                <regex>false</regex>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```